# Try to download all the csv from the ipython console from datacamp

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ipython

In the working space I have bunch of csv

```
'summer_xxx1.csv'
'summer_xxx2.csv'
'summer_xxx3.csv'
```

that is accesssable from the remote ipython command shell , I want to download them to local machine and try to make sense out of them.

I have try following code

```py
import base64
from IPython.display import HTML

def create_download_link(df, title = "Download CSV file", filename = "data.csv"):  
    csv = df.to_csv()
    b64 = base64.b64encode(csv.encode())
    payload = b64.decode()
    html = '<a download="{filename}" href="data:text/csv;base64, {payload}" target="_blank">{title}</a>'
    html = html.format(payload=payload,title=title,filename=filename)
    return HTML(html)
```

Here `create_download_link(medals_df)` would return `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`

Is there way to make medals_df to csv and downloadable from the ipython command shell

Comment: have you tried using the ! command to use unix bash commands in order to just copy all of them with *.csv ?

Comment: Not working, Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, Sorry to ask again, but are there any updated answers?

Answer (score 1):

For everyone who still faces the same problem, you can check the detailed answer [here](https://anhhaibkhn.github.io/Data-Science-selfstudy-notes-Blog/datacamp/dataset/download/ipython%20shell/2022/09/21/How-to-download-datasets-from-IPython-Shell.html).

or use the following code in the shell:

```
import base64
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
from pathlib import Path


def create_download_link( df, title = "Download CSV file", filename = "data.csv"):

    filename = Path.cwd() / filename
    df.to_csv(filename)

    in_file  = open(filename, "rb")
    csv = in_file.read()
    # print(csv) # Uncomment this if you want to check the csv content
    in_file.close()

    b64 = base64.b64encode(csv)
    payload = b64.decode()
    html = '<a download="{filename}" href="data:text/csv;base64,{payload}" target="_blank">{title}</a>'
    html = html.format(payload=payload,title=title,filename=filename)
    # print the link
    print("data:text/csv;base64,{}".format(payload))
    return HTML(html)

create_download_link(df)
print(df.info())
```

you can then paste the print output string into your browser's new tab to download your needed dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The .csv and .tsv files are posted on the overview page for the unit and you can download them from there.

Comment: Yeah, I rebuild the DF from the csv, take a bit of time but working actually

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add all of the downloaded files to a Jupyter notebook, you can use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574021/efficiently-importing-multiple-csvs-as-multiple-pandas-dataframes-not-merging)

Answer (score 0):

- first, **open any datacamp course** , it contains dataset section

[image: datacamp dataset]

- click on file , will be **downloaded as `.p` file** (which is a pickle file)
- **read pickle file using pandas**

```
import pandas as pd 
df=pd.read_pickle("filename.p")
print(df)
```